# xrandr transform makes cursor invisible

Tags: intel-graphics, 15.10, xrandr, ubuntu-gnome

I need to make the following transformation for an external display as described [here](https://newagesoldier.com/linux-hdmi-resize-screen-overscan-fix-ubuntu/):

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --transform 1.06,0,-65,0,1.06,-34,0,0,1
```

However, such a command makes the cursor invisible (but, note, "usable").
I noticed that the problem occurs only when shifting the screen:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --transform 1.06,0,0,0,1.06,0,0,0,1
```

won't indeed cause the problem.
Still, I need to shift it.

Is there a solution or workaround? Should I file a bug?

Comment: same here in 2019 - Ubuntu 18.04 using: `xrandr --output 'eDP-1' --auto --pos 0x2160 --scale 1x1 --output 'DP-3' --auto --scale 2x2 --pos 0x0`